# Unable to understand, what is meant by Headless CMS

Tags: wordpress

What is Headless CMS ? I googled about this, and the explanation is not convincing for me.. What is this relation with Gatsby and Wordpress ?

Can somebody explain this in simple terms ?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article on Headless CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_content_management_system). Headless CMSes (apparently) deliver/present content in response to API requests from a separate, unrelated front end, but still seem to manage the content itself. Wordpress contains both of these features (its "monolithic" i.e. everything [content management and presentation] is done in one package). Gatsby creates static pages ahead of time (i.e. not on the fly) and thus is unlike Wordpress or any headless CMS.

Answer (score 1):

A headless CMS is one that does not have a front-end, such that the content the CMS contains can be delivered to whateevr front-end the developer chooses to implement.

A headless (or "decoupled") CMS uses an API that the front-end developer uses, therefore meaning there is no one single front-end the developer is restricted to using.

For example, without complex scripting, WordPress has a back-end and a front-end all developed as a single product to give users the ability to manage content and it directly interacts with its own database.

In contrast, ButterCMS (among many others), is an API-based blog engine that can be interfaced with whatever technology you choose for your project to implement a blog. You would require complex scripting to do the same with WordPress, if at all.

Additionally, a headless CMS is not restricted to just providing a CMS for a website. It can be used with anything that can make calls to an API - mobile apps, client apps installed on user PCs, etc.